# Using Lock in muti-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, locking

I am trying to save images from three cameras at the same moment using muti(3)-threads and press of a button.

I picked a [code online](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/video/webcamvideostream.py) and created three object instance. The threads are running fine and windows are display and can save the images. But i am not sure if i am using the "Locks"(acquire&release) in right sense. In total there are 4 locks.

```
Current Code:
#!/usr/bin/env python

from threading import Thread, Lock
import cv2

class WebcamVideoStream :
    def __init__(self, src = 0, width = 1024, height = 768) :
        # width = 320, height = 240
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
        self.started = False
        self.read_lock = Lock()

    def start(self) :
        if self.started :
            print "already started!!"
            return None
        self.started = True
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.start()
        return self

    def update(self) :
        while self.started :
            #if self.stream.grab():
                #(grabbed, frame) = self.stream.retrieve()
            (grabbed, frame) = self.stream.read()
            self.read_lock.acquire()
            self.grabbed, self.frame = grabbed, frame
            self.read_lock.release()

    def read(self) :
        self.read_lock.acquire()
        frame = self.frame.copy()
        self.read_lock.release()
        return frame

    def stop(self) :
        self.started = False
        self.thread.join()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback) :
        self.stream.release()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    mainer_lock = Lock()
    vs = WebcamVideoStream(src = 0).start()
    vs2 = WebcamVideoStream(src = 1).start()
    vs3 = WebcamVideoStream(src = 2).start()

    while True :
        frame = vs.read()
        frame2 = vs2.read()
        frame3 = vs3.read()
        cv2.imshow('webcam', frame)
        cv2.imshow('webcam2', frame2)
        cv2.imshow('webcam3', frame3)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 99:
            mainer_lock.acquire()
            cv2.imwrite('cam_pics/frame.jpg', frame)
            cv2.imwrite('cam_pics/frame2.jpg', frame2)
            cv2.imwrite('cam_pics/frame3.jpg', frame3)
            mainer_lock.release()

    vs.stop()
    vs2.stop()
    vs3.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need lock at all.

First, `mainer_lock` is meaningless. I know you want use it to protect `frame[2, 3]` from being changed by `vs[2, 3]`. But it is impossible as the `frame[2, 3]` in main thread is a copy of original frame(I suppose you are using `copy` rightly). `vs[2, 3]` will only change the frame inside their instances, and it won't affect the frame in main thread.

Second, `read_lock` is also meaningless. Do you really mind that the frame is changed while being read? As you are capturing real frames, the consequent frames are almost the same. So let's say you want capture frame at 1000ms but Oh because of threads competition you actually capture frame at 1002ms. But does it really matter? As far as I think, it doesn't.